# Unable to activate Miniconda environment on Travis VM

Tags: travis-ci, conda, miniconda

I'm trying to use Miniconda inside a Travis VM (Ubuntu Xenial). My `.travis.yml` contains the line `install: ./get_miniconda.sh; ~/miniconda3/bin/activate` where `get_miniconda.sh` is the following script:

```
wget http://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -bf
```

The installation is successful but activating the base environment fails with `CondaValueError: The target prefix is the base prefix. Aborting.` which is absolutely meaningless to me. I can also not reproduce this on any of my local systems.

Does someone know what this error message is trying to tell me?

Comment: With the latest versions of conda (4.6 and up), executing the activate script is no longer the appropriate way to activate the base environment. You should try something like `~/miniconda3/bin/conda activate base` I think

Comment: Thanks, that did it. But I would still like to know what that error actually means because this is the second time I've seen it to today, the other time when trying to create a new environment from a yaml file.

Comment: I'd suggest searching for that message in the conda code: https://github.com/conda/conda/search?q=The+target+prefix+is+the+base+prefix&unscoped_q=The+target+prefix+is+the+base+prefix